# show the core plot chart in a table view cell using ios and xcode3

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos, operating-system

I am now working on an iphone project. I want to use a core plot chart into a table view cell in ios. I am using xcode3 and ios 4.2 versions. Now the chart is displayed in a separate view. By touching the row in a table view, the chart should be displayed below the row as a table view cell. Can you help me?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

[Core plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) uses CPTGraphHostingView to be placed on an UIView. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW15) you can find how to add subviews to an UIViewTable cell view.